# Run an Executable on all Files in a Directory and Get Different Output Files Corresponding to the Original Files

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, executable, csh

I have a Redhat Linux terminal program that utilizes the following command:
Program inputfile outputfile

Inputfile is the name of the file that I want modified and outputfile is the name of the output file.

I need a c shell command that can run the program on all files in the same directory (001p.pdb all the way to 361p.pdb) and create the output files with the names 001h.pdb, 002h.pdb ... 361h.pdb

Comment: Good luck! When you are stuck and have some code to show us please update you question and we'll gladly help. Right now, I'm afraid you will not get any answers without showing some effort yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sh as the sub-shell in the following instead of csh would likely be faster, but the code below will work in any shell:

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\./[0-9][0-9][0-9]p\.pdb' | xargs -I _IN_ csh -c 'program _IN_ `echo _IN_ | sed -e s/p/h/`'
```

Assumption is that the files are in the current working directory -- but the command can easily be extended to take care of arbitrary directories.

Comment: I also have files with characters (capital letters, numbers, underscore) with a pdb extenstion. If I want the output to just have an h before the extension (pdb), how would I modify this code? I would think you would do $\.pdb' | xargs ..... is this correct?

Comment: How about we just say -regex '[^h]\.pdb' ? does this work for you?

Comment: Or -regex '[^h][.]pdb' ? Putting the . within brackets potects against CSH  pulling the \ ?  (I never did have a great handle on CSH escaping rules...)